# php a and b players consecutive stones

Tags: php, math

I have to find a php code to solve a math problem.

This is the problem description:

> Players A and B are playing a new game of stones. There are **N** stones
>   placed on the ground, forming a sequence. The stones are labeled **from
>   1 to N**. Players A and B play in turns take exactly two consecutive stones
>   on the ground until there are no consecutive stones on the ground.
>   That is, each player can take stone **i** and stone **i+1**, where **1≤i≤N−1**. If
>   the number of stone left is odd, A wins. Otherwise, B wins. Assume
>   both A and B play optimally and A plays first, do you know who the
>   winner is?
>
> The line has N stones and are indexed from 1 to N --> **N  (1 ≤
>   N ≤ 10 000 000)**
>
> If the number of stone left is odd, A wins. Otherwise, B wins.

This is my code. It does work, but it is not correct.

```
        <?php
$nStones =  rand(1, 10000000);
$string = ("i");
$start = rand(1, 10000000);
$length = 2;
while($nStones > 0) {
    substr( $nStones , $start [,  $length ]): string;
}
if ($nStones % 2 == 1) {
    echo "A";
} else {
echo "B";
}
?>
```

I think am missing the alternant subtraction of two consecutive stones by A & B, while $nStones > 0. Furthermore, the problem description mentions an optima subtraction until there is only one stone left. Therefore I guess the stones move together to their closest stones (the gaps disappear and are replaced by the closest stones).

Comment: What do you mean by "two consecutive stones"? I.e. when two stones are removed, are the stone just to the left and the stone just to the right now consecutive, or is there now a break in the line? Also, what "math problem" is your code to solve? Is it to play a winning strategy, or prove the statement "If the number of stone left is odd, A wins. Otherwise, B wins," or print who will win for a given number `N` of stones, or something else? By the way, this is neither the game of Nim or using the Nim programming language, so you should remove that tag.

Comment: Hi Rory! Two consecutive stones: i and i+1 (i.ex. 2 and 3). Then, 1 (to the left) will not have any consecutive, and 4  will have 5 as a consecutive (if is still there). I have to find the proper php code which returns the solution "if the number is odd, A wins. Otherwise, B wins". Like the coin flip. I assume that N is a random number, because of the N: (1 ≤ N ≤ 10 000 000). It can be different in different games.

 Thanks for the quick answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a start here:

```
<?php
class GameOfStones
{
    const STONE_PAIR = 'OO';
    const GAP_PAIR   = '__';

    public $line;

    public function __construct($length)
    {
        $this->line = str_pad('', $length, self::STONE_PAIR);
    }

    // Removes a pair of stones from the line at nth location.
    public function remove($n)
    {
        if(substr($this->line, $n-1, 2) == self::STONE_PAIR)
            $this->line =
                substr_replace($this->line, self::GAP_PAIR , $n-1, 2);
        else
            throw new Exception('Invalid move.');
    }

    // Check if there are no further possible moves.
    public function is_finished()
    {
        return strpos($this->line, self::STONE_PAIR) === false;
    }

    // Representation of line.
    public function __toString()
    {
        return implode('.', str_split($this->line)) ."\n";
    }
};

$game = new GameOfStones(6);
echo $game;
var_dump($game->is_finished());
$game->remove(5);
echo $game;
var_dump($game->is_finished());
$game->remove(2);
echo $game;
var_dump($game->is_finished());
```

Output:

```
O.O.O.O.O.O
bool(false)
O.O.O.O._._
bool(false)
O._._.O._._
bool(true)
```

Currently this class starts by making a line which is a string of 'O' characters.

So if the length was 5, the line would be a string like this:

```
OOOOO
```

The remove method takes an index.  If that index was 1, first the line is checked at the string's 0 index (your n-1) for two consecutive O's.  In other words 'are there stones to remove at a given position?'.  If there are stones, we do a string replacement at that position, and swap the two Os for two _s.

The is_finished method checks the line for the first occurance of two Os.  In other words if there are two consecutive stones there is still a move on the line to play.

The magic method __toString, is the string representation of a GameOfStones object.  That's used as a way to visualise the state of the game.

```
O.O.O.O._._
```

The above shows four stones and two gaps (I'm not sure if the dot separators are necessary - the underscores can bleed into each other that's why I've used them).

I have added example use of the code, where (two) pairs of stones are removed from a line of six stones.  After each removal we check if there is another possible move, or rather if the game has ended.

There is no player attribution currently, that's left to you.

Your last rule:

> 'If the number of stone left is odd, A wins. Otherwise, B wins.'

I am struggling with.  See these examples:

```
i) Line of length 3:

OOO 
O__ A (1)

End: one (odd) stone left.

ii) Line of length 4:

OOOO
OO__ A (3)
____ B (1)

End: zero (even) stones left.

ii) Line of length 7:

OOOOOOO
O__OOOO A(1)
O__O__O B(5)

End: three (odd) stones left.
```

I'd say that the person that removes the pair so the next player can't go is the winner.  In game ii) above if A had played at position 1 (`O__O`), then they would prevent B from playing.

Comment: Can you explain what are you doing? I imagined that the code will be much shorter. I see now that I was wrong. But I want to know why all these: class, public function, etc. Then I wonder in "if(array_slice($stones, $n-1, 2) == ['_', '_'])", if "if(array_slice($stones, $n, 2) == ['_', '_'])" would be better, since the players choose n-stone, and pick the following too (n+1). Thanks for your time!

Comment: I've changed the stone line representation to a string now, and just use string functions to test if there are two underscores in a row somewhere on the line as a condition that you can play.  It should be easier to follow.

Comment: Is this creating N number of stones? public function __construct($length)
    {
        $this->stones = str_repeat('_', $length);
    }

Comment: @Underfunk I have made some name changes to hopefully reflect your problem better.

Comment: I want to understand what your code does. Can you tell me a little about it? I thought that I found a solution, but I was wrong.

Comment: Now I get it! You made stones (0)!!! How awesome! Really! But what I need is the solution (the winner), who plays optimally, for a given number of N (random). Thank you very much! I will analyze your code to understand what you do in each part.

Comment: I added a brief overview of the code.  If it's not clear from the class definition, then that's a severe failure on my part.

Comment: I have been thinking about the game rules. I guess the stones move their position to their closest ones (like in a pile due to gravity). That is the only way the players could remove two consecutive stones and finish the game with one left stone. In this case, A will always win when N is odd, otherwise B wins. I am reading your overview.

Comment: This is the problem description: "players A and B are playing a new game of stones. There are N stones placed on the ground, forming a sequence. The stones are labeled from 1 to N.

Players A and B in turns take exactly two consecutive stones on the ground until there are no consecutive stones on the ground. That is, each player can take stone i and stone i+1, where 1≤i≤N−1. If the number of stone left is odd, A wins. Otherwise, B wins.

Assume both A and B play optimally and A plays first, do you know who the winner is?"

Comment: @Underfunk anyway that's my interpretation of the problem/game you outlined, no gravity defined!  You can tell with your question comments that people were struggling to interpret your aims.  Please edit your question to clarify what you are modelling, what you've tried and your existing outcome, and how they differ to your expected outcomes.

Comment: Now I totally understand it. I misunderstood this "If the number of stone left is odd, A wins". It led me to think that the stones left moved their position. It is a grammar thing. I am not English native speaker. And last, I assumed that N is the number of stones, so it can be up to 10^7 stones. Thanks for your effort! I really learned :)